mUnits and Error Handling - How to mock error error.muleMessage
1.On error Propagate config in my flow  
2. error.muleMessage place in my flow
I want to create an MUnit test case for a flow implemented in onError Propagate with the condition #[["422", "500", "503", "504"] contains (error.muleMessage.attributes.statusCode as String)]. I need to test this scenario without specifying an error type. I can create an error with a custom description using the format #[java!java::lang::Exception::new('custom error with status code 422')], but it always sets the value in error.description. I need to set that value in error.muleMessage. Any ideas?
I tried several approaches including this one  #[java!java::lang::Exception::new('custom status code 422')], but they all failed.
My Munit version is 2.3.0 and Mule version is 4.3.0 and
my flow snippet:
<flow name="APIFlow" doc:id="bcad673e-0a5b-4947-af6c-24f8fbb1cf15">
    <try doc:name="Try" doc:id="946da0b7-c772-4864-9594-d980c7c927be">
        <http:request method="POST" doc:name="API Call" doc:id="aa0565f5-c01f-4918-a908-2af4ddeda71d" config-ref="HTTP_Highway_configuration" path="#[vars.Details.path]" responseTimeout="30000">
            <http:headers><![CDATA[#[output application/java
                ---
                {
                    "Authorization": vars.Token
                }
            ]]]></http:headers>
            <http:uri-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
                ---
                {
                    "Number": vars.caseno
                }
            ]]]></http:uri-params>
        </http:request>
        <error-handler>
            <on-error-propagate enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Propagate" doc:id="a848f0e0-7b33-4a76-ada1-12d16cba70b9" when='#[["422", "500", "503", "504"] contains (error.muleMessage.attributes.statusCode as String)]'>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="c82776b9-e5bb-4385-a86f-d955255c6b37" message="API call failed...Retrying"/>
                <set-variable value="#[true]" doc:name="Set failure flag" doc:id="42ec01cf-2b5c-45e1-8922-42945c675c66" variableName="Failure"/>
            </on-error-propagate>
            <on-error-continue enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Continue" doc:id="20ba7c7e-434f-421b-b392-691c02f46cf6">
                <set-variable value="#[true]" doc:name="Set failure flag" doc:id="46484ec4-cf39-43cb-a798-d99c999dca09" variableName="Failure"/>
            </on-error-continue>
        </error-handler>
    </try>
</flow>

i have tried multiple methods including try mocking the exception class to,make custom error message in the exception field
#[java!java::lang::Exception::new('API Call failed with status code 422')]

Why do you need to set error.muleMessage? And why you don't want to set the error type? Which versions of Mule and MUnit are you using? [edit] the question to add a [mre].

In my normal flow we use On Error Propagate with  ,so when creating munit gives issues,like mocking this error require error.muleMessage.Munit version is 2.3.0 and Mule version is 2.3.5

The version of Mule must be something like 4.x.x. Please share the correct version.

And share a complete minimal test and flow in the question, not in comments([mre]). It is hard to say what you are trying to test exactly.

Did you try the solution here: How to raise a Custom Error With Internal payload (error.errorMessage.payload) in MUnit. I remember it helped me but there was a catch that it always throws MULE:UNKNOWN. since you are not relying on it it should not be a problem for you as well. I wish Mule had provided an easy way for it as it is such a common scenario

Mule error handling uses Mule errors, not exceptions.

I tried this method as well, but it didn't set the value to error.muleMessage; I'm still getting a null value there.But error.Message i can see the value is being set.

If I want to mock error.muleMessage, I could use #[java!java::lang::Exception::new('API Call failed with status code 422')], but I want to use error.muleMessage instead.

Trying to use error.muleMessage is a mistake. It is undocumented and not accessible in recent versions of Mule because of internal changes for Java 17 compatibility.

Yeah I missed you were using error.muleMessage and not the error.errorMessage. To add what aled said, you should be using errorMessage only. Any particular reason to why you are muleMessage ?

I understand that, but is there any way to modify Mule's internal code to customize and set a value for error.muleMessage? For example, can we mock the condition #[["422", "500", "503", "504"] contains (error.muleMessage.attributes.statusCode as String)] by throwing a Mule message? I can customize an exception class to throw an error with a message and description using #[java!java::lang::Exception::new('API Call failed with status code 422')].

If it's undocumented and inaccessible in recent versions of Mule due to internal changes for Java 17 compatibility (I am using Java 8), then what is the point of adding this attribute to the error? It doesn't make any sense

I agree, there are a lot of additional fields that are accessible but are not supposed to be used, and it creates a lot of confusion and noise. If you have to use muleMessage, you can try to populate it using reflection.

The question linked in Harshank's comment is close to what I do for tests like this, where I want to produce an error from a mock that is similar to the one that comes from a connector, including attributes and payload.  What I have done is to create a flow in my munit suite that really does raise the same kind of error, if I can, and then use <munit-tools:then-call> in my mock to force the error.
In your case, it seems you can create a HTTP listener flow that simply responds with one of your intended status codes, and use an HTTP request in a flow inside your munit suite to send the HTTP request.

I tried this method as well, but it didn't set the value to error.muleMessage; I'm still getting a null value there.

I followed these steps:

I created a .dwl file under src/test/resources/test/SetHttpError.dwl.
The script in the .dwl file is almost same as what harshank provided
3.I used a separate flow and set the event using munit-tools:set-event and placed the value in the exception as follows:
#[output application/java --- readUrl('classpath://test/SetHttpError.dwl')]


i am getting this error ""Exception while reading 'classpath:/test...' as 'application/dw' cause by:Missing Object Field Expression. e.g  {a: 123}1| classpath://test/SetHttpError.dwl
^Trace:at root::main (line: 1, column: 57)1| output application/json  --- read('classpath://test/SetHttpError.dwl')Trace:at read (line: 1, column: 35) at main (line: 1, column: 30)" evaluating expression: "output application/json  --- read('classpath://stest/SetHttpError.dwl')"."

I think you may be limited by what set-event is capable of.  I don't use set-event, I make a real HTTP error. That way I get everything in the error event that would happen with a real connector.

How do you typically trigger a real HTTP error in your tests? Could you provide an example or best practices on how to set this up in an MUnit test to ensure all error attributes, including error.muleMessage, are properly populated?
